# Eclipse dark theme debugging tables not readable

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubeide

I'm using STM32CubeIDE, which is based on Eclipse IDE for C/C++ programming of STM chips.
ST added a Serial Wire Viewer extension, which among other things provides this table (contents are not too important for my question):
[table - 'highlighted' text is not readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnCeM.png)

As you can see - the cells that has some higher percentage are almost unreadable.
It seems to be using the same colors for the 'normal' eclipse debugging table-like features such as Variables, Live Expressions, Expressions, etc.

I tried looking for the highlight color and messing with settings but could not find anything that affects it.
I even went out and made a Google Sheets with all colors listed in the settings file to try to match that highlight color with no success.

It is also generally difficult to understand which color setting affect which part of the program, but that's another issue.

Comment: The _SWV Statistical Profiling_ view is not a view of the Eclipse platform or CDT, but a view that STM32CubeIDE adds. So it might be a color that can be changed in the preferences _General > Color and Fonts_, in the preference somewhere else (in the _Preferences_ dialog search/filter for `color`), somewhere else (is there something in the view menu (the three dots)?) or the color might hard-coded by STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: @howlger I am aware the the SWV features are STM32CubeIDE's additions. Anyway the colors in these tables are the same as in other debugging tables (that are actually Eclipse native) so I was looking for the settings to edit these colors, hoping SWV tables inherit these settings.